# Add another Admin Grid View from same block instances

Tags: admin, adminhtml, grid, backend

I currently have an admin grid view per file structure/code as below;

**Block/Adminhtml/Things.php**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_things';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'things';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('things')->__('Things Grid');
    $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('things')->__('Create Enhanced News Item');
    parent::__construct();
}
```

**Block/Adminhtml/Things/Grid.php**

```
public function __construct()
{

    //... (Sorts etc)

    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('things/things')->getCollection();

    //Use this in another Grid to filter
    //$collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('notnull' => true));
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{

    //... (columns)

   return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

**controllers/Adminhtml/Things/ThingsController.php**

```
public function indexAction() {

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();

}


public function gridAction() {

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('things/adminhtml_things_grid')->toHtml());

}
```

**layout/things/things.xml**

```
<adminhtml_things_things_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="things/adminhtml_things" name="things" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_things_things_index>
```

and all works fine and I have a populated **Grid view** via adminurl/things_things/index (grid view)

but how do create another Grid View with filtered collection? Do I;

1. Copy all the  Block & controller files and rename/refactor the namespace (ie Things2) and add the view into the xml layout file or;
2. Add another view action inside the ThingsController.php & xml layout file as well as creating another Grid block File with the collection filter ie Block/Adminhtml/Things/Grid2.php

Comment: I have tried to copy the files and change "things" to "things2" but I get the Fatal error: Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession() on a non-object error

Answer (score 0):

Used option 1 and refactored/renamed copied files of all the "things" & "Things" namings to "otherthings" & "Otherthings"..

But in the copied & renamed file Block/Adminhtml/Otherthings/Grid.php

I have **not changed** the _blockgroup

```
 $this->_blockGroup = 'things';//kept module name and not changed to "otherthings" naming
```

as this stopped the error that i explained in the comments i was getting and successfully got a new filtered collection grid view on a new backend url..

Plus..

As I only wanted to copied the Grid Files *(and not the complete edit view & tab view files as not really wanting to edit two groups of file sets when file edts/improvents are needed)* i needed the edit link in the grid view to point back to the original edit page url (ie adminurl/things_things/edit/id/13/key/3449574385634857) if not, I would get a 404, i changed the code in the edit column inside the copied grid file as per below;

```
//new copied file
Block/Adminhtml/Otherthings/Grid.php

//Edit Link Column point back to original edit url
$this->addColumn('action', array(
   'header' => Mage::helper('things')->__('Edit Item'),
   'width' => '100',
    'type' => 'action',
    'getter' => 'getId',
    'actions' => array(
      array(
        'caption' => Mage::helper('things')->__('Edit'),
        'url' => array(
            //point back to original edit URL
            'base' => '*/things_things/edit'
         ),
         'field' => 'id'
           )
       ),
     'filter' => false,
     'sortable' => false,
     'index' => 'stores',
     'is_system' => true
    ));
```